# modifier and signature of the function

Tags: solidity

I would like a piece of advice about a modifier I am setting up, please.

I have this function:

```
/**
        @notice determines if the address Ethereum is stakeHolder or not
        @param _address are you a stakeholder?
        @return bool whether you are stakeholder or not
        <!> it works with Remix!
*/
    function isStakeholder(address _address) public view returns(bool, uint256){

        for (uint256 i=0; i < stakeholders.length; i += 1){
            if( _address == stakeholders[i])
                return (true, i);

        }
        return (false, 0);
    }
```

And this modifier associated with this function:

```
/**
   @notice modifier to check if the current address is a stakeholder/admin or not
*/
    modifier onlyStakeholderOrOwnerOfContract(address _address){
        uint256 i;
        require(isStakeholder(_address) == true || msg.sender == ownerOfContract, "this address is not a stakeholder");
        _;
    }
```

When I run the command `truffle migrate --reset`, I have this result:

```
Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Compiling ./contracts/Staking.sol

TypeError: Operator == not compatible with types tuple(bool,uint256) and bool
  --> /Users/alexandre/WebstormProjects/alyraChallenge4Stacking/contracts/Staking.sol:72:17:
   |
72 |         require(isStakeholder(_address) == true || msg.sender == ownerOfContract, "this address is not a stakeholder");
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Compilation failed. See above.
Truffle v5.3.13 (core: 5.3.13)
Node v12.22.7
```

Obviously, it is because of the return of the function doesn't fit with the modifier.

I would like to keep the multi-type return of the function.

Have you got any idea how to put the `i` in the modifier to be OK with my function?

Answer (score 0):

You could split it in two steps :

```
modifier onlyStakeholderOrOwnerOfContract(address _address) {
    (bool stakeholderFlag, ) = isStakeHolder(_address);
    require(stakeholderFlag == true || msg.sender == owner, "the address is not a stakeholder");
    _;
}
```

If you really want to get the integer variable too simply change it to :

```
modifier onlyStakeholderOrOwnerOfContract(address _address) {
    (bool stakeholderFlag, uint256 i) = isStakeHolder(_address);
    require(stakeholderFlag == true || msg.sender == owner, "the address is not a stakeholder");
    _;
}
```

If you want more informations about handling tuples in solidity, you can refer to the [current documentation](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.10/control-structures.html?highlight=tuples#destructuring-assignments-and-returning-multiple-values).

Comment: I found the solution thanks to the suggestion of hroussille. I will write it soon.